# Generate random number without srand

Tags: c++, random

I need to generate a random number with srand. I used :

```
std::default_random_engine generator;
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(1,6);
int dice_roll = distribution(generator);  // generates number in the range 1..6
```

but it keeps generating same number.

Comment: Without srand, it will always generate the same sequence of numbers.

Comment: In the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) it's shown that you need a `std::random_device` to initialise the random engine.

Comment: how do i intialise that random device?

Comment: @OfirNissim There's an example in the linked documentation.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thank you very much man it works!!

Answer (score 1):

Use random device to get random initialization from the runtime (from the OS)

```
std::random_device rand_dev;
std::default_random_engine generator(rand_dev());
```

Note, it is also possible to pick your own seed:

```
std::default_random_engine generator(3752);
```